# want to set strike in textview in listview

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have ListView in which I have to display TextView with custom layout. I'm displaying the list of task with due date. Now I want to set strike effect on text of TextView which have due date was after with current date I am able to set but as I have scroll the view it's change means its set on today's date or tomorrow's date task.

here is my code :

```
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View view;

     Date due_date = new Date(due_date_long);

     if (convertView == null) {
         view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tasks_row2, null);
         ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
         holder.text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);//Task Title
         view.setTag(holder);
     }else{
         view = convertView;
     }
     ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
     holder.text1.setText(task_title);
     //if(YESTERDAY.equals(task_date))
     if(cur_date.after(due_date))
         holder.text1.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very common problem you will have to write the else part of this line

```
if(cur_date.after(due_date))
     holder.text1.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
else
     // set something which default for textview
```

Comment: I want to set strike effect on expired task so only if condition was required and by default was as it is no need to put the else part

Comment: this is in listview so when scroll the list or open any task and closed then some of current task or after todays task will be effected with the strike

Comment: yeah I know that, thats why I am saying in else part set the textview to their default bcoz listview works on recycling the views just gave it a try it will solve your problem