# Android: Striking out a check list item once checked like in Google Keep

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I'm working on an app wherein I'm allowing the user to add notes and check list like in Google Keep. So the challenging I'm facing right now is once the check list is checked I need to strike the text out. Any idea how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the check box click by  onCheckedChangedListener in getView method.

Refer this [blog](http://lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html) and you find sample [here](https://github.com/lalit3686/ListViewCheckBox)

And to strike the textview use paint flag

```
TextView tv=(TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

See this SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7484525/792232)

Answer (score 6):

Play with custom view and grab the selected position of checked item and set `paintFlags` like below:

```
 yourTextView.setPaintFlags(yourTextView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: Thank you. I shall give it a shot and get back to you with my results.  :)